# How to Simulate While Loops in Scratch?

Tags: mit-scratch

In most programming languages, there is a "while" loop that runs code while a condition is true. However, in Scratch, there is only a "repeat until" loop that repeats until a condition is true. How do I simulate a "while" loop in Scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you wanted to use a "while" loop to run while "ConditionA" is true.

WHILE ConditionA
 Say "hello"

In Scratch, you can use a "repeat until" loop in this way:

REPEAT UNTIL NOT ConditionA
 Say "hello"

Answer (score 1):

This is easy. Just loop an "if" operator.

```
forever
  if <...>
    code goes here
  else
  end
end
```